# LUA: howto omit a value of a multi-value in a multiple-assignment

Tags: lua, multiple-assignment

If I want only the first and the third value of the function f(), I can do the following:

```
local a, _, b = f();
```

Since `_` is a valid name, maybe `_` gets assigned a large table.

Is there a way to omit this assignent to `_` in the above case? (Clearly: if `_` goes out of scope it is gc'ed).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible but maybe just adding `_ = nil` on the next line is the best alternative

Comment: @IvoBeckers that's definitely the simplest solution. the cases where this is actually necessary should be very very rare.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it helps but maybe you can define a helper function like

```
function firstAndThird(a, b, c)
    return a, c
end
```

and then use it like

```
local a, b = firstAndThird(f());
```

Comment: Or `function firstAndThird(a,b,c) return a,c end` to avoid creating a table.

Comment: @lhf yeah that's even better. don't know why I didn't think of that haha. I'll edit my answer to make it like that

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to omit this assignent to _ in the above case?

No there is no way to omit that assignment if you need the third return value. You can only make sure not to keep the returned object  alive by referring to it through `_`. Of course this only makes a difference if there is no other reference left.

In addition to using a function to limit `_`'s  scope you can also use `do end`

```
local a,c
do
  local _ a,_,c = f()
end
```

or you simply remove the unused reference.

```
local a, _, c = f()
_ = nil
```

Comment: I think some newlines would improve your code a lot. At first I didn't get the syntax you used in the first example, until i realised I would write the same code over several lines if I wrote it myself. Putting everything on one line can be nice at times but it shouldn't cause any confusion. But what's suitable as one-liner or not is of course a bit subjective.

Comment: @IvoBeckers the only time I use a one-liner per year and you catch me :D